# Is there a name for date/time interval format like "1h10m"

Tags: date, datetime, duration, dateinterval

It's commonplace even outside of software to communicate time or date intervals in a truncated manner. For example: `1h10m` translates to "One hour and ten minutes."

This could be abstracted to a set of rules. For instance: A date interval is represented as a combination of `_h`, `_m`, (and so on), where `_` characters represent non-negative integers or floats, which are summed into one date interval object.

Mixing days, hours, minutes are allowed. For example, `0.5d1h60m` would be a synonym for `14h`.

Is there a standard defined out there anywhere that resembles this?

Comment: That's a **Duration**: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: Also, be careful because the term "day" can have two different meanings depending on context.  In a pure elapsed-time context, a day is 24 hours, but in most contexts we mean a *calendar* day.  Due to discontinuities in local time (such as daylight saving time), a modern "day" can be 23, 23.5, 24, 24.5, or 25 hours in duration, depending on which day and which time zone you are talking about.  In other words, `P1D` and `PT24H` (using ISO8601 syntax) are not necessarily the same thing.

Comment: Likewise, `P1M` != `P30D`, and `P1Y` != `P365D`, because months, years, and the aforementioned days are not necessarily fixed units.

Comment: In some cases again, a year is a fixed unit, e.g. for most banks a year is always 360 days when used for interest calculations. Better know your domain.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard for this is a **Duration**, defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).
Note that an **Interval** is a different concept (also defined by the same ISO), although both are closely related:

- A **Duration** defines an **amount** of time (like "1 hour and 10 minutes" or "2 years, 3 months and 4 days"). But it doesn't tell you when it starts or ends ("1 hours and 10 minutes" relative to what?). It's just the amount of time, by itself.
- An **Interval** (quoting wikipedia) is *"the intervening time between two time points"*. It has a defined start and end dates, but you can use a **Duration** to define it, as it can have 4 different formats:

  1. Start and end, such as `2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z`
  2. Start and duration, such as `2007-03-01T13:00:00Z/P1Y2M10DT2H30M`
  3. Duration and end, such as `P1Y2M10DT2H30M/2008-05-11T15:30:00Z`
  4. Duration only, such as `P1Y2M10DT2H30M`, **with additional context information**

Cases 1, 2 and 3 are equivalent (all have the same start and end dates). The only difference is that in cases 2 and 3, the duration `P1Y2M10DT2H30M` is used to calculate the other date (in case 2, you add it to the start date, and in case 3 you subtract it from the end date).

---

As you can notice above, the standard format for a **Duration** is `P[n]Y[n]M[n]DT[n]H[n]M[n]S`, where:

- P is the duration designator (for period) placed at the start of the duration representation.
- Y is the year designator that follows the value for the number of years.
- M is the month designator that follows the value for the number of months.
- W is the week designator that follows the value for the number of weeks.
- D is the day designator that follows the value for the number of days.
- T is the time designator that precedes the time components of the representation.
- H is the hour designator that follows the value for the number of hours.
- M is the minute designator that follows the value for the number of minutes.
- S is the second designator that follows the value for the number of seconds.

So, "1 year and 10 months" is represented as `P1Y10M` and "1 hour and 10 minutes" is `PT1H10M` (note that the `T` is required to resolve the potencial ambiguity between 1 month (`P1M`) and 1 minute (`PT1M`), as they use the same letter `M` as designator).

---

As @MattJohnson commented, the math with dates it's not always obvious, so the equivalence between different durations can't be what we normally expect.

For the examples below, I'm using Java 8 (just to show how durations can be tricky). Note that the `java.time` API uses 2 different classes (`Period` and `Duration`), but the idea for both is the same (they're both amounts of time).

- A duration of 1 month is equivalent to how many days? It depends:

  ```java
  // one month period
  Period oneMonth = Period.parse("P1M");
  // January 1st
  LocalDate jan = LocalDate.of(2016, 1, 1);
  System.out.println(jan); // 2016-01-01
  // January 1st plus 1 month period = February 1st
  LocalDate feb = jan.plus(oneMonth);
  System.out.println(feb); // 2016-02-01
  // February 1st plus 1 month period = March 1st
  LocalDate mar = feb.plus(oneMonth);
  System.out.println(mar); // 2016-03-01

  // difference between Jan 1st and Feb 1st = 31 days
  System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(jan, feb)); // 31
  // difference between Feb 1st and Mar 1st = 29 days (2016 is leap year)
  System.out.println(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(feb, mar)); // 29
  ```

So, adding 1 month to *January 1<sup>st</sup>* results in *February 1<sup>st</sup>* - in this case, 1 month is equivalent 31 days (A.K.A. **adding a 1 month duration (`P1M`) is equivalent to adding a 31 days duration (`P31D`)**), and adding 1 month to *February 1<sup>st</sup>* results in *March 1<sup>st</sup>* (in this case, 1 month = 29 days, because 2016 is a leap year).

- 1 day = 24 hours? Not always. If there's a [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) shift involved, you can get strange results:

  ```java
  // 1 day period
  Period oneDay = Period.parse("P1D");
  // 24 hours period
  Duration twentyFourHours = Duration.parse("PT24H");
  // in Sao Paulo, summer time starts at Oct 15, at midnight
  // getting a date one day before DST change, at 10:00 AM
  ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.of(2017, 10, 14, 10, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
  System.out.println(z); // 2017-10-14T10:00-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

  // add 1 day - gets the same hour (10:00 AM)
  System.out.println(z.plus(oneDay)); // 2017-10-15T10:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

  // add 24 hours - gets 11:00 AM because of DST shift (at midnight, clocks moved forward 1 hour)
  System.out.println(z.plus(twentyFourHours)); // 2017-10-15T11:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
  ```

In São Paulo, at *October 15<sup>th</sup>, 2017*, DST starts (clocks are moved forward by 1 hour), so:

- If you add **24 hours** to *October 14<sup>th</sup> at 10 AM*, you'll get *October 15<sup>th</sup> at **11** AM*
- But if you add **1 day**, you'll get *October 15<sup>th</sup> at **10** AM*

So, in this case, 1 day = 23 hours - **it means that adding a 1 day duration (`P1D`) is equivalent to adding a 23 hours duration (`PT23H`)**

When DST ends, is the opposite: clocks move back 1 hour, and 1 day will be equivalent to 25 hours.

So, the standard defines the format and meaning of the amounts of time concepts, but the equivalence between different durations will depend on the context (although it might sound non-intuitive that 1 day is not always 24 hours, but date/time math is not as obvious as we'd like).

Comment: Very precise and insightful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

```
moment.duration(100); // 100 milliseconds
moment.duration(60000).humanize(); // a minute
```

Read more in the above linked docs. And to get all unit values you may want to use the ISO8601 Format:

```
moment.duration(1, 'd').toISOString() // "P1D"
```

For example, "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".
Read more directly under http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/as-iso-string/