# Parsing the ISO-8601 duration values of the AMAZON.DURATION slot type

Tags: java, duration, java-time, alexa-skills-kit, period

Does the `java.time` library provide a consolidated way to parse the entire [ISO-8601 Duration Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)?

The [Alexa Slot Type reference for duration](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/built-in-intent-ref/slot-type-reference#duration) lists some example strings to expect when using the AMAZON.DURATION slot type. All strings are in ISO-8601 Duration, but `P2YT3H10` cannot be parsed by either `java.time.Period` or `java.time.Duration`.

```
Seq(
 "PT10M",
 "PT5H",
 "P3D",
 "PT45S",
 "P8W",
 "P7Y",
 "PT5H10M",
 "P2YT3H10"
).map { s =>
 s -> Try {
   try {
     Period.parse(s)
   } catch {
     case ex: Throwable => Duration.parse(s)
   }
 }.map(x => x.toString -> x.getClass.getSimpleName)
}
.foreach(println)
```

Results:

```
(PT10M,Success((PT10M,Duration)))
(PT5H,Success((PT5H,Duration)))
(P3D,Success((P3D,Period)))
(PT45S,Success((PT45S,Duration)))
(P8W,Success((P56D,Period)))
(P7Y,Success((P7Y,Period)))
(PT5H10M,Success((PT5H10M,Duration)))
(P2YT3H10,Failure(java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text cannot be parsed to a Duration))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hugos answer is only related to one detail aspect of the ISO-8601-standard, namely the combination of date and time part with a "T"-separator. This detail is indeed not supported by `java.time` but supported by the external library Threeten-Extra (using the class `PeriodDuration` in the version v1.2). However:

### The ISO-8601-standard describes even more variations.

One variation is the usage of weeks in the form "P8W". Both `java.time` and Threeten-Extra automatically change it to "P56D" but don't leave it in week-related form when parsing and formatting. A similar view can be obtained when looking at the time components. `java.time.Duration` cannot directly store hours or minutes but automatically convert it to seconds. When formatting an automatical normalization is performed, too. Example:

```
System.out.println(Duration.parse("PT4200S")); // PT1H10M
```

So in both cases: **What you put inside during construction is not always what you get when formatting**.

Other points:

- **Duration representations in ISO-8601 (as specified in section 4.4.4.2)** are always called "Duration" (even if date-related) while `java.time` uses two different terms, namely `Period` and `Duration` (either date-related or time-related).
- **Week-related durations** are handled separately since two standard ways in ISO-8601-notation are described: "PnnYnnMnnDTnnHnnMnnS" or "PnnW".
- **Signs don't exist in ISO-8601-specification** (see section 3.4.2: symbol "n" defined as positive integer or zero) while `java.time` allows signs even inside the representations and interprete signs as component-related. Note that XML-Schema only handles signs preceding the whole duration expression (before "P"), that is not component-related but duration-related.
- **Alternative representations of durations** are also specified, either in basic or in extended format: "PYYYYMMDDThhmmss" resp. "PYYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss".
- **Handling of fractional seconds**: ISO-8601 speaks about usage of comma or dot (and even explicitly prefers the comma) while `java.time.Duration` only supports the dot.

**Finally we can state:**

The ISO-8601-standard is only partially supported by `java.time` (and Threeten-Extra which only supports the combination of the classes `Period` and `java.time.Duration` as additional detail).

**Alternative solution for true ISO-8601-support:**

If you want or even need to overcome the limitations baked into `java.time` then you can use my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) which supports all the additional details of ISO-8601. See the API of class [net.time4j.Duration](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/Duration.html#parsePeriod-java.lang.String-). Following examples also show the compatibility with `java.time`:

```
Duration<CalendarUnit> d1 = Duration.parseCalendarPeriod("P8W");
System.out.println(d1); // P8W
System.out.println(d1.getPartialAmount(CalendarUnit.WEEKS)); // 8
System.out.println(Duration.Formatter.ofPattern(CalendarUnit.class, "W' weeks'").format(d1)); // 8 weeks
System.out.println(PrettyTime.of(Locale.GERMAN).print(d1)); // 8 Wochen
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(2017, 9, 17);
System.out.println(PlainDate.from(ld).plus(d1)); // 2017-11-12
System.out.println(PlainDate.of(2017, 9, 17).plus(d1)); // 2017-11-12

Duration<IsoUnit> d2 = Duration.parsePeriod("P2DT5H10M");
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 17, 19, 15);
System.out.println(PlainTimestamp.from(ldt).plus(d2)); // 2017-09-20T00:25
System.out.println(PlainTimestamp.of(2017, 9, 17, 19, 15).plus(d2)); // 2017-09-20T00:25
System.out.println(PrettyTime.of(Locale.GERMAN).print(d2)); // 2 Tage, 5 Stunden und 10 Minuten

Duration<IsoUnit> d3 = Duration.parsePeriod("P0001-01-02T05:10:04");
System.out.println(d3); // P1Y1M2DT5H10M4S
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 9, 17, 19, 15);
System.out.println(PlainTimestamp.from(ldt).plus(d3)); // 2018-10-20T00:25:04
```

Side note: Formatting of durations is possible in actually 86 languages.

Answer (score 6):

<sup>**PS**: your input is missing the designator for the last field (`P2YT3H10`- 2 years, 3 hours and 10 what?). So, in the code below, I just assumed that it was `M` (minutes) - it won't work without a designator after `10`.</sup>

---

The `java.time` API has separated the ISO8601 duration [in 2 classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html):

- `java.time.Period`, that can handle [date-based fields (years, months and days)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html)
- `java.time.Duration`, that can handle [time-based fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html)* (actually, according to javadoc: *"This class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of seconds and nanoseconds. It can be accessed using other duration-based units, such as minutes and hours"*)

Unfortunately, those classes can't handle an ISO8601 duration with both date and time based fields.

One alternative is to use the [ThreeTen Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, that contains some extensions for `java.time` API. With this lib, you can use the [`org.threeten.extra.PeriodDuration` class](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html), which can parse full ISO8601 durations:

```
PeriodDuration pd = PeriodDuration.parse("P2YT3H10M");
```

Then you can get the respective `Period` and `Duration` from it:

```
System.out.println(pd.getPeriod()); // P2Y
System.out.println(pd.getDuration()); // PT3H10M
```

---

Another alternative is to split the `String`, and parse both `Period` and `Duration` separately:

```
// split in 2 parts
String input = "P2YT3H10M";
String[] v = input.split("T");
Period p;
Duration d;
if (v.length == 1) { // has only date-based fields
    p = Period.parse(input);
    d = Duration.ZERO;
} else {
    if ("P".equals(v[0])) { // has only time-based fields
        p = Period.ZERO;
    } else {
        p = Period.parse(v[0]);
    }
    d = Duration.parse("PT" + v[1]);
}
```

---

*A `Duration` also accepts **days**, and those are always considered to have 24 hours (in a `Period`, a day [doesn't necessarily have 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44676793/7605325) due to Daylight Saving Time effects).

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 Duration only allows days, hours, minutes and seconds:

The formats accepted are based on the ISO-8601 duration format PnDTnHnMn.nS

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-